# EaselJS object positions change when scaling canvas

Tags: canvas, responsive, easeljs

I'm scaling my canvas using the following resize function:

```
function resize() {
    var w, h;
    var size = [1920, 1080];
    ratio = size[0] / size[1];
    if (window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight >= ratio) {
        w = window.innerHeight * ratio;
        h = window.innerHeight;
    } else {
        w = window.innerWidth;
        h = window.innerWidth / ratio;
    }
    $('canvas').width(w);
    $('canvas').height(h);

    var scale = w/1920;
    stage.scaleX = stage.scaleY = scale;

}
window.onresize = resize;
```

With HTML and CSS

```
<canvas width="1920" height="1080"></canvas>
<style>
   canvas {
       width: 1920px;
       height: 1080px;
       position: absolute;
       top: 50%;
       left: 50%;
       transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
   }
</style>
```

This works perfectly for the stage itself, but the content scaling and positions seem to shift and are not working.

So if I later have:

```
some_container.y = 1000;
```

That renders in the middle on a biggish canvas, but as I resize it moves closer to the top and, seemingly at least, isn't in proportion either.

So I guess I somehow have to apply the same ratio to the positions, but I just can't seem to get the formula right. Any help would be appreciated.

This example (https://codepen.io/funktion/pen/JwwwBx) seems to scale and move correctly.

On trial and error, I've discovered that the problem lies with the ticker...

```
createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", tick);

function tick(event) {
    if (!event.paused) {
        stage.update();
    }
}
```

BUT...I DO need the ticker for animation. Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few notes:

1. Scaling the stage is not super-advisable. There are some reported issues with mouse interaction. Better to put stuff in a container and scale that
2. If you do scale a container (or the stage), the coordinates will scale too. So something at [50,50] in a container scaled 2x would still say they were at [50,50], but would visually be at [100,100].
3. Scaling a canvas using CSS is not advisable. It transforms the pixels. It is better to set the `width` and `height` of the canvas to the size you want. Sometimes we set the canvas to 2x or 0.5x the number of pixels, and then counter-scale it with CSS to basically "zoom" it. Its a good way to either have less pixels (less fidelity, faster), or more (high-resolution), but that would be the only time I would use CSS.

I updated your codepen with the following resize code, and it worked well (I think)

Before (CSS scaling)

```
$('canvas').width(w);
$('canvas').height(h);
```

After (JS scaling)

```
stage.canvas.width = w;
stage.canvas.height = h;
stage.update(); // Must update because a resize clears the stage.
```

I also got rid of the CSS width/height on the canvas. Here is an updated pen: https://codepen.io/lannymcnie/pen/vvPLWb

I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Thanks @Lanny. Would you mind editing the actual Codepen itself so that I can see the changes? In my Codepen you'll see that it DOES scale properly, but only if the Ticker is off...which of course is not really an option.